# How to set value to control after action call complete using jquery in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Having the link like :

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("SortList", "Controllername", new { sortBy = "companyname"})"> COMMUNITY NAME </a>
```

want to set value of search text box under which this sort is going on. Don't want to use Ajax call here since some parameters will loss if doing so. Is there any way to set by using javascript handler ?

**EDITED:** 
In short want to ask is there any concept where javascript function can execute after action link call rather Ajax call.

Comment: Unclear what your asking. What _search text box_ and what do you want to set its value to?

Comment: Still not clear, but no, because you have already left the page. But your comment _Don't want to use Ajax call here since some parameters will loss if doing so_ does not really make sense (there is no reason you should 'lose anything')